# Из массива строку php

Tags: алгоритм, php

Как создать из массива строку? Все значения, изначально, хранятся по отдельности в массиве. Например, у меня есть массив имен, и мне нужно получить все значения в одной строке.

Comment: нормально сформулируйте вопрос т.к. складывается впечатление того, что вы сами не знаете что именно вам нужно, екстрасенсов здесь нет...

Comment: а вдруг, у меня есть массив имен, мне нужно получить все значения только в видео строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем непонятно что именно вы имеете введу, как я понимаю это xD

```
<?
    $names = array('Вася','Гриша','Маша','Жора');
    for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++) {
        echo $names[$i]; //выведет имя...
    }
?>
```

Так-же, если вы имеете введу массив в строку то:

```
<?
    $names = array('Вася','Гриша','Маша','Жора');
    $namesString = implode(' ', $names);
    //вместо пробела можно подствалять любую строку...

    echo $namesString;
    //Выведет: Вася Гриша Маша Жора
?>
```

Comment: Я же говорил экстрасенсы есть тут)